# JSF component is not getting reloaded for page refresh

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I am new to JSF framework and Facelets as view, I am stuck with a problem now. I have got a page where i show some dropdown menu using `<h:selectOneMenu>` tag. On each selection i used to fire an ajax event using `<f:ajax>` event it all are working fine. But my problem is, if i select an option 2 on a select box and if I reloads the page again that particular select box will be selected with option 2 by default. I dont need this. I have to reload the select boxes along with page refresh. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selectbox shows the option that is set in the backing bean (and bound by the `value` attribute of `<h:selectOneMenu>`). The behavior after a page refresh depends on the scope of your backing bean. If it is session scoped, a page refresh doesn't reset the bean. You could change the scope to @ViewScoped to get the desired behavior. The bean then will be recreated after a full request.

Comment: thanks matt for your quick reply. however my backing bean is RequestScoped.

Comment: One more thing i have to added is that i am using value attribute of the <h:selectOneMenu> to bind the property of the backing bean. When i used the binding attribute for setting the backing bean property it shows this error. "The 'binding' attribute requires an EL value binding reference to a UIComponent". I am sorry, I just started with JSF now only. So got a lot of doubts.

Comment: @Krishna You cannot use the binding attribute for this purpose. It is used to bind a component and not the value.

Answer (score 0):

Just set null to backing bean property that used in selectonemenu value after the selected action or set default value in property get method.

Comment: thanks besc, my list is an ordered list and i want to show it in the same way in the dropdown box. Actually it is coming in the same ordered way, but the selected option will be the previous one which the user has selected. Even after the page refresh it maintains the same state.